# Polymer 1.0 routing: <google-map> component is not refreshing with new Lat/Lng values inside dom-repeat

Tags: google-maps, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a customer list. Each of the customer routes to its details page. In the detail page the JSON has lat and lng defined for each record.

**JSON stirng**

```html
<script>
Polymer({  
  ready: function(){
  this.customers = [
    { "cuname": "msi", "name": "Microsoft India", "addr": "2, Strand Road", "addr2": "Kolkata, IN", "phone": "332.245.9910", "lat": "22.589091", "lng": "88.352359", "branches": [
      { "branch": "Hyderabad", "email": "hydho@cyfoxpapers.com", "phone": "1582012244", "address": "69/A, Twisted Road, Banjara Hills, Hyderabad: 600001", "code": "CPHYD" }]},
    { "cuname": "googindia", "name": "Google India Inc.", "addr": "6/B, Pragati Apartment", "addr2": "Pitampura, New Delhi, IN", "phone": "493.050.2010", "lat": "28.61598", "lng": "77.244382" },
    { "cuname": "gabonint", "name": "Gabon Internationl", "addr": "187 Kabi Kirandhan Road", "addr2": "Bhadrakali, IN", "phone": "983.193.3166", "lat": "22.665979", "lng": "88.348134" },
    { "cuname": "itg", "name": "India Tour Guides", "addr": "115/5 Palash Sarani", "addr2": "Amritsar, India", "phone": "943.390.9166", "lat": "31.604877", "lng": "74.572276" },
    { "cuname": "creatad", "name": "Creative Ad Agency", "addr": "25 BPMB Saranai", "addr2": "McLeodganj, Dharamsala. IN", "phone": "943.390.9166", "lat": "32.232596", "lng": "76.324327" }
    ];
  }
});        
</script>
```

**Route configuration**

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function () {  
    page('/location/:name', function (data) {
            app.route = 'customer-location';
            app.params = data.params;
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I come to the detail page (using the route), the element iterates the array properly (within a `dom-repeat` template) and loads all values. But the map is not refreshing itself to load respective location.

**Google map block**

```html
<div flex id="map-canvas">
  <google-map id="gmap" latitude$="{{getLatitude(item.lat)}}" longitude$="{{getLongitude(item.lng)}}" fit mapType="roadmap" zoom="10">
    <google-map-marker latitude$="{{getLatitude(item.lat)}}" longitude$="{{getLongitude(item.lng)}}" draggable="true" title="Go Giants!"></google-map-marker>
  </google-map>
</div>
```

I tried both `latitude$={{item.lat}}` and `latitude$={{getLatitude(item.lat)}}` (**Computed Property**) but none worked. It is always showing the last location on map.

```
getLatitude: function (value) {
   return parseFloat(value);
},
```

However, if I manually refresh the page by pressing `F5` map shows correct location.

**Note**: The map block is placed inside `<template is="dom-repeat"></template>`.

Can't figure out what is wrong!Looking for an expert help.

Regards

Comment: Maybe you should load map after the dom is ready...

Comment: $(domument).ready(function(){//map code here})

Comment: Fwiw, you don't need `$=` and computed property or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @so_jin_ee I don't really want to use jQuery or any library other than Polymer core script in my application.

Answer (score 0):

A similar sounding bug was recently fixed https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/138

Make sure you have the updated version.

Comment: Why should I use an observer when the value want to bind is coming directly from JSON string? Won't the map update itself? I didn't quite understand the what is written here: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/blob/master/google-map.html#L328. Please consider my poor start up knowledge about Polymer. It would be a great help if you please provide me the code based on what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks so much!